# Exit build in Jenkins when script fails

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am running Jenkins as a CI/CD pipeline for a project. To make things easier for my self, I have created a bash script to run the tests and send coverage report, here is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $GIT_COMMIT # only needed for debugging
GIT_COMMIT=$(git log | grep -m1 -oE '[^ ]+$')
echo $GIT_COMMIT # only needed for debugging

./cc-test-reporter before-build
yarn test --coverage
./cc-test-reporter after-build -t simplecov --exit-code $? || echo  “Skipping Code Climate coverage upload”
```

And this is how I am running it in Jenkins:

```
sh "jenkins/scripts/load_env_variables.sh test"
```

Jenkins runs the script, however when the script fails, Jenkins does not exit, rather it continues:

[image: Jenkins build does not exit]

Any help with this please?

Comment: Is your script exiting with a nonzero status code? Make sure it's *telling* Jenkins that there was a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "set -e" in script.

```
 -e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.
```